# How to set custom positions in recyclerview gridlayout manager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have twelve items. I use recyclerview along with GridLayoutmanager to display items. My current code

```
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerViewSlots.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

has give following format[image: List of items]

I want to display items in the following format.

[image: List of items]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by reversing both: grid layout manager and list of objects that you are passing to the grid adapter.

So if your full code with adapter assignment looks like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
YourGridAdapter adapter = new YourGridAdapter(numbers);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSlots);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Then you can just change it into:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
Collections.reverse(numbers);
YourGridAdapter adapter = new YourGridAdapter(numbers);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSlots);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

If that does not satisfy you and you have static number of items you could also consider using [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout) and putting inside of it all 12 views with manual positioning in xml.